# how to convert a div values into a csv file in a specific file name and specific path

Tags: javascript, html, csv

i am having a div element which consists of table. The table values are taken fron a json array and i have to create a new row of array and it also displayed ina table now using a export button i have to export a table valus in a csv file in a specific filename and in a specific path.
export:

```
$("#export").click(function(e) {
    alert('inside export method');
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    //getting data from our div that contains the HTML table
    var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var table_div = document.getElementById('exportdata');
    var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    alert(table_html);

    a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
    //setting the file name
    alert("pname"+pname);
    a.download = 'export.xls';
    alert('after got a id');
    //triggering the function
    a.click();

    //just in case, prevent default behaviour
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

this is a code for xls but i have to store the values in csv file and the name have to specific and everytime of exporting the valu should updated in a same file as a last row.

html:

```
<div id="exportdata">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped tablelink">

<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'issueno'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
        ISSUE NO
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'issueno' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'issueno' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'dateassigned'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
      DATE ASSIGNED
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'dateassigned' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'dateassigned' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'assignedby'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
      ASSIGNEDBY
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'assignedby' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'assignedby' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'issuetype'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
      ISSUE TYPE
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'issuetype' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'issuetype' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'priority'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
      PRIORITY
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'priority' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'priority' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'targetdate'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
      TARGET DATE
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'targetdate' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'targetdate' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'status'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
      STATUS
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'status' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'status' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'attachment'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
      ATTACHMENT
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'attachment' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'attachment' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td  style='visibility:hidden'>
      <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'description'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
      DESCRIPTION
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'description' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'description' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="roll in sushi | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchcon">
    <td ng-click="display(roll.issueno);"><a href="#">{{ roll.issueno }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ roll.dateassigned }}</td>
    <td>{{ roll.assignedby }}</td>
    <td>{{ roll.issuetype}}</td>
    <td>{{ roll.priority}}</td>
    <td>{{ roll.targetdate}}</td>
    <td>{{ roll.status}}</td>
    <td>{{ roll.attachment}}</td>
    <td style='visibility:hidden'>{{roll.description}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="newr">
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

using some export button and the file should be replaces every time when a new record is stored in a table

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `angular-file-saver` package for saving the file.

And the better way is to iterate directly through your model `sushi` not through generated HTML.

Comment: i did not know about that angular-file-saver